# Number base conversion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

How can I convert a number from one base, $b_1 \neq 10$ to another base $b_2 \neq 10$ without going through base $10$ i.e. $b_1\rightarrow 10 \rightarrow b_2$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: You can do it, but you have to do arithmetic in base $b_1$.  If you're using a computer, it's easy.  If you are using pencil-and-paper, it may be easier to convert through base 10.

---

The algorithm to convert a number $x$ to base $b$ is:

1. Set $n = 0$
2. Divide $x$ by $b$, yielding a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$
3. Digit $r_n$ of the answer is $r$
4. If $q = 0$, halt; the answer is $r_{n}r_{n-1}\ldots r_0$.
5. Set $x = q$, $n = n+1$ and return to step 2

Let's say you want to convert `1e6` (base 17) to base 7.

We set $x = $ `1e6` and $n=0$.  We divide $x$ by 7, yielding a quotient of `48` and a remainder of 1, so $r_0 = 1$ and return to step 2.

Now we divide `48` by 7, yielding a quotient of `a` and a remainder of 6, so $r_1 = 6$ and we return to step 2.

Now we divide `a` by 7 yielding a quotient of `1` and a remainder of 3, so $r_2 = 3$ and we return to step 2.

Now we divide `1` by 7 yielding a quotient of `0` and a remainder of 1, so $r_3 = 1$ and since $q=0$ we halt.

The answer is $1361_7$.

Comment: but this is because the computer can do mathematical operation in base $16$. Can I do the inverse of what you did with a computer i.e. converting from base $7$ to base $16$ without going through decimal?

Comment: I didn't use a computer; I did it by hand using my brain and a piece of paper. I will redo the example converting from base 17 so that you are not confused.

Comment: sorry, my bad. How did you divide *1e7* by *7* in base $16$?

Comment: I used the usual short division algorithm for base 10, but in base 16 instead.  `1e` divided by 7 is `4` with a remainder of 2; `47` divided by 7 is `a` with a remainder of 1, so the quotient is `4a` and the remainder is 1.

Comment: @F'OlaYinka [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/259045/25554) has some discussion of pencil-and-paper arithmetic in bases other than 10.

Comment: Thank you, you've been of great help.

Comment: In this answer, does "the quotient `q`" refer to the quotient with the remainder, or the quotient without the remainder?

Comment: It means the quotient without the remainder. The remainder is $r$.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do arithmetic in base $b_1$, you can use the technique of repeatedly dividing by $b_2$ and reading off the remainders in reverse order. For example to convert $261_{\text{seven}}$ to base four, you can carry out the following calculation (which is entirely in base seven):

$$\begin{align*}
261&=4\cdot50+1\\
50&=4\cdot11+3\\
11&=4\cdot2+0\\
2&=4\cdot0+2
\end{align*}$$

Thus, $261_{\text{seven}}=2031_{\text{four}}$.

To see why it works, imagine that we’ve already written the number in base four. The remainder after division by four is just the unit’s (= least significant) digit, and the integer quotient is what’s left when that digit is removed.

For the reverse conversion, done entirely in base four:

$$\begin{align*}
2031&=13\cdot110+1\\
110&=13\cdot2+12\\
2&=13\cdot0+2
\end{align*}$$

Of course the middle digit has to be written $6$ in base seven instead of the base four $12$, but we get $2031_{\text{four}}=261_{\text{seven}}$, as expected.