# Moving between bases

Tags: number-theory

Is there any kind of method to move between bases?

I know that there are methods to convert between base x to base y, but I'm looking for something general which won't limit me. Is it possible? Maybe there is some kind of equation.

Comment: What is limiting you in the usual way to go from one basis to another?

Comment: What is the usual way?

Comment: You said you know there are methods. I assumed that meant you actually knew some of those methods.

Comment: Yes there are some methods to move for example from binary base to hex-decimal.

Comment: `(number).toString(base)` for bases up to $36$, or you can adapt this [JavaScript code](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert3.htm) to work with bases above $36$.

Comment: We just answered this today at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313954/number-base-conversion/313962#313962

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two different algorithms you might want to use for converting a number $n$ from base $x$ to base $y$, depending on whether you'd rather do your arithmetic in base $x$ or base $y$.

**If you're more comfortable doing arithmetic in your starting base:**

Write $n=ay+b$ where $0 \leq b < y$ (that is, do "division with remainder" on $n$). Then $b$ will be the rightmost digit of your new representation of $n$, and you repeat the process on $a$ to get all the other digits. Stop when $a$ is less than $y$ (at which point $a$ will be the leftmost digit of your number).

For example, say we want to write the base-ten number $23504$ in base $7$. Then:

- $23504$ divided by $7$ is $3357$ with a remainder of $5$, so the rightmost digit is $5$.
- $3357$ divided by $7$ is $479$ with a remainder of $4$, so the next-to-rightmost digit is $4$.
- $479$ divided by $7$ is $68$ with a remainder of $3$, so the next digit is a $3$.
- $68$ divided by $7$ is $9$ with a remainder of $5$, so the next digit is a $5$.
- $9$ divided by $7$ is $1$ with a remainder of $2$, so the two leftmost digits are $12$.

Putting all this together, we have $23504_{\mathrm{ten}}=125345_7$.

**If you're more comfortable doing arithmetic in your ending base:**

Start at the left end of your number and keep a running total. As long as you still have more digits, multiply your running total by $x$ and add the next digit to it. When you run out of digits, your running total is the converted number.

For example, say we want to write the base-$7$ number $125345_7$ in base ten. Then:

- We haven't added anything yet, so our running total is $0$. Multiply by $7$ and add the leftmost digit $(1)$ to get $1$.
- Our running total is $1$. Multiply by $7$ and add the next digit $(2)$ to get $9$.
- Our running total is $9$. Multiply by $7$ and add the next digit $(5)$ to get $68$.
- Our running total is $68$. Multiply by $7$ and add the next digit $(3)$ to get $479$.
- Our running total is $479$. Multiply by $7$ and add the next digit $(4)$ to get $3357$.
- Our running total is $3357$. Multiply by $7$ and add the next digit $(5)$ to get $23504$. Since we're now all out of digits, this is the base-$10$ representation of the number.

So again this demonstrates that $125345_7=23504_{\mathrm{ten}}$ (but starting from the other end).

Finally, maybe you're not comfortable doing arithmetic in *either* base. If there's some base $z$ you are comfortable doing arithmetic in, that's OK! Just use the second algorithm to convert from base $x$ to base $z$, and the first one to convert from base $z$ to base $y$.

Answer (score 1):

To change bases you use the division algorithm: for an integer $n$ (in any base) and new base $y$, there exists a quotient $q$ and remainder $r$ such that
$$n = qy + r, \qquad 0\leq r < y.$$
You can compute $q$ and $r$ by performing long division of $n$ by $y$ in base $x$.

The remainder $r$ then becomes the least significant digit (ones digit) of the number $n$ in base $y$. Repeat the process, using $q$ for $n$, to find the next digits.