# Raise a number to the "y" power without using exponents.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, exponentiation

This is kind of a spinoff on my question [Divide by a number without dividing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/393071/56935)

Can anyone think of some clever ways to raise any given number to any given power without using an exponent anywhere in your equation/formula?

$$x^{y}=z$$

Comment: Anti-log of $y\log x$.

Comment: One thing I was thinking of was $\int{y*x}$ but you would end up with a $±Constant$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Wouldn't it be the `anti-log base x of y`? Either way that one's a little bit sketchy, an anti-log is just exponents basically. But it still works so I'll plus one that. (User's must keep in mind that the exponent in the anti-log formula is just the notation for writing anti-log, you are not actually raising it to the negative first power. $log^{-1}_{x}(y)$

Comment: Your title says $n$th power, which implies $n$ is an integer, but your question says $x^y$ where $y$, by implication, is not an integer.  Integer powers can be efficiently compute using the Exponentiation by Squaring method. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well I meant for all numbers, not just integers, I thought that a double stricken "z" stood for integers only, not an "n", anyways, the `exponentiation by squaring` still involves exponents in the formula.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw, "exponentiation by squaring" involves _no_ exponentiantion, just multiplications.

Comment: There's only one base in grownup mathematics, and that's $e$. Anti-log of $Q$ is a way of writing $e^Q$ without writing an exponent.

Comment: The term $n$th is an *ordinal*, which implies that $n$ is a natural number. We never say "I finished in  $\sqrt{2}$th place in the race!" Also, while $\mathbb Z$ represents the *set* of integers,  $n$ as a variable tends to imply a natural number or integer. Not a hard rule, just a convention. But the real problem is that you switch variables and *never specify what you mean* in either case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Corrected the title! Thanks for your help :o)

Comment: @GerryMyerson, does information theory not count as grownup mathematics? It uses base 2 more than $e$.

Comment: @Peter, OK, I'll give you base 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use the Taylor series for $f(u) = e^u$.

$$
x^y = 1 + y \ln x + \frac{(y \ln x)(y \ln x)}{2!} + \frac{(y \ln x)(y \ln x)(y \ln x)}{3!} + \cdots
$$

Comment: Very nice! :) Factorials have always fascinated me, it seems like they would be an ideal way to exponentiate since they involve sets of multiplication.

Comment: Now that I understand more intuitively what logarithms actually are I redact my above comment. This is still a nice solution though :D